# Flexbox different behaviour between chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

While using flexbox for placement of elements inside container, I'm getting strange results in chrome when in firefox all works correctly

This is the container html:

```
<fieldset class="addtobasket-container>
  <div class="button_wrap">
    <button type="submit" class="addtobasket">
    </button>
  </div>
  <a class="addtofav">
  </a>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.addtobasket-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
}

.button-wrap {
  min-width: 40%;
  height: 100%
}

.addtobasket-container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
}

.addtobasket {
  max-width: 230px;
  height: 54px;
}
```

In Firefox all works good:

[image]

Unfortunately in chrome it's always in separate rows:

[image]

Can't find what's the problem here. Any suggestions?